# multiple data queries php ajax mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost:8889", "root", "root", "Testdata");
if(!link) {echo "Database connexion not possible"; exit;}
$id = $_GET('testeId');
$jsonData = [];
```

The first query is working:

```
$jsonData['table1'] = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registerData WHERE testeId = $id";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $jsonData['table1'][] = $row;
  }
}
else {
  $jsonData['table1'][] = "Error 1";
}
```

This second query is not working:

```
$jsonData['table2'] = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM factsData WHERE factsId = $id";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql){
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jsonData['table2'][] = $row;
  }
}
else {
  $jsonData['table2'][] = "Error 2";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

The jsonData string only includes the 1st query:

```
mysqli_close($link);
```

The responseText of the ajax request only has data from "table1" array

Comment: It also looks like you're mixing the `mysqli` interface with the deprecated, dead `mysql_query` one. That `i` character is significant.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Probably $id in second query should be replaced with something different

Comment: If the second query isn't working, there's probably an error-message waiting for you, add `mysqli_error($link);` in an `else` to your `if` where you check the query - although if you're connecting with `mysql_` that won't work with `mysqli_` (but if one query is working, then you're actually connecting with the proper API). Also, general error-reporting might tell you something `error_reporting(E_ALL);` `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: Actually, I'm using mysqli_connect (it was a copy error ...)

Comment: @M.Veloso Alright - then what does `echo mysqli_error($link);` give you? Or the PHP error-reporting?